# O separador está atravessando o botão reset

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout-responsivo

Eu queria que o separador parasse pouco abaixo dos botões FREE THROW, e não no fim da tela. Como faço para corrigir de forma que o design seja responsivo?

Porque o conteúdo fica desorganizado quando a tela está no modo landscape?

[image: Tela em modo portrait]

[image: Tela em modo landscape]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context="com.example.android.courtcount.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Team A"
            android:textColor="#616161"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/team_a_score"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="0"
            android:textSize="56sp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:onClick="add3CurrentTeamAScore"
            android:text="+3" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:onClick="add2CurrentTeamAScore"
            android:text="+2" />


        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="add1CurrentTeamAScore"
            android:text="Free Throw" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"></View>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Team B"
            android:textColor="#616161"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/team_b_score"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="0"
            android:textSize="56sp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:onClick="add3CurrentTeamBScore"
            android:text="+3" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:onClick="add2CurrentTeamBScore"
            android:text="+2" />


        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="add1CurrentTeamBScore"
            android:text="Free Throw" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="resetScores"
    android:text="Reset" />
```

Comment: Poderias criar um layout em landscape..só criar uma pasta "layout-land" e fazer o teu xml personalizado lá dentro, daí podes economizar um espaço do label "Team".

Answer (score 1):

Você poderia criar uma pasta chamada "layout-land", lá dentro você adiciona novos arquivos de layout que serão utilizados quando o celular estiver em landscape.

É dificil criar um xml que se adeque a todos os dispositivos e vertical/horizontal por uma série de fatores, dentre eles, o mais impactante era o tamanho das telas dos outros dispositivos.